# Dyslexia in the Workplace as an adult and lost opportunities because of it

Tags: discrimination, disability, mental-health, distractions, california

I work in the IT field and sometimes I make mistakes and mostly its due to my dyslexia.

I spell names incorrectly, incorrectly categorize tickets in the system, accidentally click on buttons I should not have, or send e-mails to someone that should not get them.

I also misrepresent numbers as letters and so on, etc.  In the past I have lost opportunities, not received raises, and been punished for this.

I have to go over things multiple times and read sentences over and over again which is exhausting for my brain.

I have been ridiculed by other colleagues which makes me feel dumb or inadequate and I just recently thought "well, this isn't really my fault and that maybe I should have a note or something from a doctor or psychologist to protect me or give me some accommodation to help me with this disability."

I live in Costa Mesa, California and work in Fountain Valley if you have any referrals.

I also have PTSD from the military and I am bi-polar, which I have a note from the VA for.

Comment: Hi Pip, reading your question it isn't clear who you are asking for. Can you edit for clarification?

Comment: To deal with the dyslexia problem, have tought of using a special police character? (see: https://www.opendyslexic.org/ ) It might really help you in your day to day life.

Comment: Thanks, what I really want is a note to show my manager and a diagnosis from a provider that I can show him that I have this disability. A test would be nice and a doctor that can do a test in my area to show my employer. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you not working in an industry that fits your skills?

Comment: What is the actual question here? What will a note do for you (and your employer)?

Answer (score 6):

Realistically you are not suitable for the role, you can ask for accommodation of your problems and may even get some. But at the end of the day you're not an asset to the company if you're constantly making mistakes like that. Therefore your chances of future advancement/good recommendations etc,. are thin.

It's a bit worrying that you didn't think it right to mention all these serious problems at the job interview or documents.

There are jobs in IT which don't have much communication or typing in them, you might want to investigate those or even contemplate changing industries to one in which you can rise in a career easier.

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement.  You are very helpful.

Answer (score 6):

As a fellow dyslexic, I feel your pain.

You CAN find strategies and methods for dealing with this, but you are going to need to work with your psychologists, and maybe even see specialists. Even then, it will be a lot of work, and probably be emotionally taxing. You may also need to find a new workplace that's more accommodating, or has engineering procedures that minimize your weaknesses (Like using stylecop or good constants).

Answer (score 3):

With the list of diagnosed issues you list I would certainly have a note.  The key is how is it affecting your work.  You already identified that it is and therefore need to take action to protect your reputation as a worker.  Being turned down as incapable is ok, although it sucks, but being turned down as not a good employee should never be the case (so long as it’s medical related and not legit).

If the employer knows then they might be able to help you strategize a coping mechanism or two in order to prevent teamwork frustration.  There are extra checking tools and you might also be able to get proofread a or something.  Just some thoughts, but you clearly need a little help to prevent workplace impact, so you should let your manager know in the professional way of a doc note and discuss symptoms and coping mechanisms to ensure work production stays satisfactory.